# Import javax.Servlet in a Java Application

Tags: java, front-controller

I anticipate that I've already read all the duplicate threads, without solving my problem.

I'm making a Java Application and I create a class, called FrontController, and I need to import these packages:

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

but I get this error on all the imports:

```
error: package javax.servlet does not exist
```

So, I tried to import the javax.servlet-api in the Glassfish path, and I've solved only 5/6 of the imports, except the "javax.servlet.HttpServlet;" import.

How could I resolve this situation? 
Does anyone know an efficient solution of the problem? Instead of importing one to one the libraries?

Important: It's not a Web Application, but it's a Java application

Comment: If it is not a Web Application, why does your code use Servlet?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because, on the university's slides, the FrontController class must extend the HttpServlet class and I must declare the ProcessRequest method, so I need to import these libraries.